# Cannot able to build on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I'm trying to build on simulator but getting warnings and errors.
I have replaced many packages with latest version but nothing happened still getting a lots of warnings.

My MacOs version: catalina 10.15.2

flutter version:1.12.13+hotfix.5

dart version:2.7.0

flutter run output console:

Errors:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2019-12-23 14:40:27.817 XCBBuildService[82944:471889] Failed to remove:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asthupoaqltbbmesqetcacindons/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuil
    dData/ad956668556b5ace65773807034d312f-manifest.xcbuild:
    unlink(/Users/brightrootssgruti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asthupoaqltbbmesqetcacindons/Build/Intermediates.noindex
    /XCBuildData/ad956668556b5ace65773807034d312f-manifest.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    2019-12-23 14:40:28.782 XCBBuildService[82944:471889] Failed to remove:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asthupoaqltbbmesqetcacindons/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuil
    dData/ad956668556b5ace65773807034d312f-desc.xcbuild:
    unlink(/Users/brightrootssgruti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asthupoaqltbbmesqetcacindons/Build/Intermediates.noindex
    /XCBuildData/ad956668556b5ace65773807034d312f-desc.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26
    :
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:32
    8:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:34
    3:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:34
    3:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:34
    3:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:36
    2:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    4 warnings generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugi
    n.m:2:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:32
    8:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:34
    3:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:34
    3:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:34
    3:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:36
    2:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugi
    n.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
        UIViewController *viewController =
                          ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugi
    n.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                        ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugi
    n.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                        ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.0/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugi
    n.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                      ^
    8 warnings generated.
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/git/plugins-441417c2fed0ff26bf84a49ab2c5ffd2aa5487de/packages/firebase_a
    uth/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:358:62: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
    [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      userData[@"lastSignInTimestamp"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:lastSignInDate];
                                         ~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRewardedV
    ideoAdWrapper.m:67:66: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'FLTRewardedVideoAdStatus' to 'int'
    [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          (NSString *)rewardedStatusToString[[NSNumber numberWithInt:_rewardedStatus]];
                                             ~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.m:71:13: warning: 'testDevices' is deprecated: Use GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        request.testDevices = testDevices;
                ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:88:71: note: 'testDevices' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSArray<NSString *> *testDevices GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                                          ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAdsDefines.h:25:56: note: expanded from macro
    'GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
    #define GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                           ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.m:91:15: warning: 'birthday' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          request.birthday =
                  ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:95:55: note: 'birthday' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSDate *birthday GAD_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                          ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAdsDefines.h:33:49: note: expanded from macro
    'GAD_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
    #define GAD_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                    ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.m:106:19: warning: 'gender' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              request.gender = genderValue;
                      ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:92:47: note: 'gender' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, assign) GADGender gender GAD_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                  ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAdsDefines.h:33:49: note: expanded from macro
    'GAD_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
    #define GAD_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                    ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.m:116:14: warning: 'tagForChildDirectedTreatment:' is deprecated:  use [GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration
    tagForChildDirectedTreatment] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [request tagForChildDirectedTreatment:childDirected.boolValue];
                 ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:126:5: note: 'tagForChildDirectedTreatment:' has been explicitly
    marked deprecated here
        GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
        ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTRequestFa
    ctory.h:5:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAdsDefines.h:25:56: note: expanded from macro
    'GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
    #define GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                           ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTMobileAd.
    m:40:17: warning: 'configureWithApplicationID:' is deprecated: Use [GADMobileAds.sharedInstance startWithCompletionHandler:]
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:appId];
                    ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTMobileAd.
    h:6:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADMobileAds.h:74:5: note: 'configureWithApplicationID:' has been explicitly marked
    deprecated here
        GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use [GADMobileAds.sharedInstance startWithCompletionHandler:]");
        ^
    In module 'GoogleMobileAds' imported from
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTMobileAd.
    h:6:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFram
    ework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAdsDefines.h:25:56: note: expanded from macro
    'GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
    #define GAD_DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                           ^
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.0+10/ios/Classes/FLTMobileAd.
    m:98:79: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'FLTMobileAdStatus' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      NSString *statusString = (NSString *)statusToString[[NSNumber numberWithInt:_status]];
                                                          ~                       ^~~~~~~
    2 warnings generated.
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'cloud_firestore' does not include header 'CloudFirestorePlugin.h'
    [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/cloud_firestore-umbrella.h"
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    <module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'firebase_admob' does not include header 'FirebaseAdMobPlugin.h'
    [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/firebase_admob-umbrella.h"
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    error: unable to read property list from file:
    /Users/brightrootssgruti/ShrutiProjects/shrutiFlutterProjects/babilok/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed.
    (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Shrutis-MacBook-Air:babilok brightrootssgruti$
```

Comment: I think you should provide some of the errors that you receive. There is not much to go with from the information you provided.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Add more information to your question, in the current format, nobody can help you.

Comment: Done, i have added errors and warnings.

Comment: is your app target checked in Xcode?

Comment: 1) Are you using the latest version of those packages ? 2) Did you installed plugins using `flutter packages get` ?

Comment: have a look at your Info.plist file..anything strange with it?

Comment: Yes , but Some of packages I updated with latest version like firebase_admob

Comment: @flutter I have  checked many times and I'm sure nothing is wrong with info.plist file. And platform :ios, '9.0'

Comment: @flutter sir, you were right, I have set the info.plist elements in wrong manner. Thank you sir.

Comment: Damn it, me too! It was the `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` set to `</true>` instead of `<string>YES</string>`

Comment: @dasfima Haha :D

Answer (score 1):

You just have to upgrade your **FlutterToast** library

`fluttertoast: ^4.0.0`

And in my case, I changed the target platform to iOS 10.0 as well in `Podfile`

`platform :ios, '10.0'`

Comment: what you mean is, inside the ios/podfile, , change the version of platform ios: version to. ahigher one